# how to hide and show some models in three.js

Tags: three.js

I want to know how can I hide and show some models in my three.js code . actually I want to know the method for write less code for hide and show my model in three.js . look at this code that I've tried .

```
let gltf_hide_show = null;
let gltf = new GLTFLoader();
gltf.load('FILE_PATH',(model_gltf)=>{
   Scene.add(model_gltf.Scene);
   gltf_hide_show = model_gltf.Scene
})
let t = true;
if(t){
   t = false;
   gltf_hide_show.visible = false; /* this code hides the model */
}
else{
   t = true;
   gltf_hide_show.visible = true /* this code shows the model */
}
```

Comment: There is no point in adding tags to the title of the question.